# Indexing a pointer to char pointers in a Struct is overwriting all values?

Tags: c, struct

I'm having a strange problem in C with a struct I'm working.  One of the structs elements is a array of char arrays of size 3.  The element is meant to be a players hand and the char arrays are meant to be the individual cards.  They're formatted like "2C" where 2 is the rank and C is a club.  My problems lies in a function that's creating the player hand from a given string.  In the loop j is meant to be the card index and at the end it assigns the created card (which I know is correct) to the index.  At the last iteration of the loop it assigns 4C and every one of the elements become 4C for some reason.  Here is the code for the function:

```
typedef struct dataStruct {
int playerCount;
int handSize;
char playerID;
char** playerHand;
} dataStruct;

void proc_new_round(struct dataStruct* data, char* input) {
int length = strlen(input), i = 9, j = 0;
char tempChar[3];
if (length != 86 && length != 59 && length != 47)
    invalid_hub_message();
else if (input[8] != ' ')
    invalid_hub_message();
alloc_hand_size(data, (length - 8) / 3);
for (j = 0; j < data->handSize; j++) {
    if (input[i] != '2' && input[i] != '3' && input[i] != '4' &&
        input[i] != '5' && input[i] != '6' && input[i] != '7' &&
        input[i] != '8' && input[i] != '9' && input[i] != 'T' &&
        input[i] != 'J' && input[i] != 'Q' && input[i] != 'K' &&
        input[i] != 'A' ) {
        invalid_hub_message();
    }
    tempChar[0] = input[i++];
    if (input[i] != 'H' && input[i] != 'D' && input[i] != 'C' &&
        input[i] != 'S' ) {
        invalid_hub_message();
    }
    tempChar[1] = input[i++];
    tempChar[2] = '\0';
    printf("tempchar %s\n", tempChar);
    data->playerHand[j] = tempChar;
    if (i < length) {
        if (input[i++] != ',')
            invalid_hub_message();
    }
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
data->playerHand[5] = "7C";
printf("%s\n", data->playerHand[5]);
printf("%s\n", data->playerHand[12]);
printf("%s\n", data->playerHand[7]);
//print_hand(data);
}
```

The input given for the function is: 
newround 2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,2C,4C
At the end of the function the 3 cards printed are 7C, 4C and 4C, but given the temp cards created it should be 7C, 4C and 2C.  My print hand function also prints out every card except index 5 as 4C.  Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: The code included is code that's related to the function, i've tested the allocation of memory for the hand so it wasn't included.

Comment: as such we have no way of replicating or testing your code

Answer (score 2):

```
    data->playerHand[j] = tempChar;
```

All the pointers in `data->playerHand` have the same value and point into the same array, `tempChar`. Whatever is written last to `tempChar` appears as the final value of all.

Your code is analogous to this:

```
int *a[4];
int tmp;
int j;

for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    tmp = j * 10;
    a[j] = &tmp;
}

int dummy = 42;
a[1] = &dummy;

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *a[0], *a[1], *a[2], *a[3]);
```

All array elements are set to point to `tmp` by the loop. `a[1]` is then overwritten to point to `dummy`. The final values of `tmp` and `dummy` are `20` and `42`, respectively, so the output is

```
20 42 20 20
```

Comment: Okay, but then how come when 
`data->playerHand[5] = "7C";` processes, not all the values are changed to "7C"?

Comment: @JessAhrens Because you're only assigning to `data->playerHand[5]`?

Comment: Yes but isn't it the same as `data->playerHand[j] = tempChar` in the context of a for loop, as j is increasing from 0 to the handsize, each iteration would increment the index wouldn't it?